# No bean named '***' is defined (Spring, Hibernate)

Tags: spring, hibernate

I just ran into a problem with my configuration. I get the following error when calling my service (No bean named '***' is defined). All other posts to this isue i found didn't help me. Any help would be really appreciated.

*dispatcher servlet:*

```
<import resource="classpath:spring/mvc-view-config.xml" />
<import resource="classpath:spring/database-config.xml" />
<import resource="classpath:spring/hibernate-config.xml" />

<context:annotation-config />

<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<context:component-scan base-package="de.christian.api*" />
```

*hibernate-config:*

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>de.christian.api.model.User</value>
            <value>de.christian.api.model.News</value>
            <value>de.christian.api.model.Tag</value>
            <value>de.christian.api.model.Project</value>
            <value>de.christian.api.model.Article</value>
            <value>de.christian.api.model.News</value>
            <value>de.christian.api.model.GuestbookEntry</value>
            <value>de.christian.api.model.News</value>
            <value>de.christian.api.model.Tag</value>
            <value>de.christian.api.model.Project</value>
            <value>de.christian.api.model.Article</value>
            <value>de.christian.api.model.News</value>
            <value>de.christian.api.model.GuestbookEntry</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager"
    p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory">
</bean>
```

*application context:*

```
<context:component-scan base-package="de.christian.api.controller" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.html</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

*service:*

```
@Service("guestbookEntryService")
public class GuestbookEntryServiceImpl implements IGuestbookEntryService {
```

*trace:*

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'guestbookEntryService' is defined
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:638)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1159)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:282)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:973)
at de.christian.api.controller.GuestbookController.getGuestbookPage(GuestbookController.java:73)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:214)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:748)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:931)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:822)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:807)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:301)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:74)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:526)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1017)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:652)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1575)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1533)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

*controller call:*

```
ConfigurableApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
gservice =          (IGuestbookEntryService)context.getBean("guestbookEntryService");
```

I hope anybody has a hint for me.

Greetings coffeeLord

Comment: You need to post the stack trace.

Comment: Sorry totally forgot that, it's now up. thanks

Comment: Just wanted to find out if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're talking about a `base-package` spring should know that it should look into deeper packages without adding `*` at the end. Please try:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="de.christian.api" />
```

For further information check [this](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-auto-scanning-components/).

Comment: Hi Jan, tried it. But still the same error. To me it seems like that the annotations do not work, but i have no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of items need to be noted. Your controllers are scanned as part of application-context.xml and your service/daos are scanned as part of dispatcher-servlet.xml. They are two different context. Try getting it from your dispatcher-servlet.xml in your controller code.